# Shiny SidebarPanel selectInput only after a checkbox was checked

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to have a Shiny sidebar panel with one Input that is always there, and one that appears only after a checkbox was checked. All of the related solutions I could find talk about using `checkboxInput` for conditionals on the `output`, but I'm not sure how I can make this happen. To show what I need, here's a snippet of my code:

```
require(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel('My App'),
    sidebarPanel(selectInput(inputId = "id1",
                         label = "something 1",
                         choices = c('a', 'b', 'c')),                 
             
                     checkboxInput("test_check", "Do you want to this?", value = FALSE),
                     uiOutput("test"), # checkbox to see if the user wants a comparison
             
                     selectInput(inputId = "id2",
                         label = "something2",
                         choices = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
    ),

    mainPanel(
        tabPanel("Some Info", htmlOutput(outputId = "info1"))
    ))

server <- function(input, output, session){}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So I want to have `id2` to appear in the sidebar only if the checkbox is checked, but can't figure out how to do it. Thanks.

EDIT: Added a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Please add a reprex of the app

Comment: Yeah, should've thought of that, thanks. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move some of the UI to the server in order to check for the box, this is what I do when one input depends on another, then you just need to use req()

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel('My App'),
  sidebarPanel(selectInput(inputId = "id1",
                           label = "something 1",
                           choices = c('a', 'b', 'c')),                 
               
               checkboxInput("test_check", "Do you want to this?", value = FALSE),
               uiOutput("test"), # checkbox to see if the user wants a comparison
               uiOutput("id2")

  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    tabPanel("Some Info", htmlOutput(outputId = "info1"))
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$id2 <- 
    renderUI({
      req(input$test_check)
      selectInput(inputId = "id2",
                  label = "something2",
                  choices = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
    })
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```